# Ignore some insert when restoring a Dump

Tags: mysql, linux

I've got a huge .gz dump and i want to ignore some useless table row.

for now i'm doing that for restoring the database :

gunzip < mydatabase-yyyy-mm-dd.gz   | mysql   -p -v

For exemple, i want to create the table accessLog but skeep all the inserted row.
And i've got 4 other table in this case.

If i could do that, restoring the db could take some minute instead of all the day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found the solution by myself:

gunzip < mydatabase-yyyy-mm-dd.gz | 
sed "/INSERT INTO `myTableName`/d" | 
sed "/INSERT INTO `myOtherTableName`/d" | 
mysql -p -v

sed width  /.../d" remove line containing the string specified, and mysqldump write each insert request in one line.